# How to install multiget on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

How do I install `multiget` on Ubuntu 18.04? When I run:

```
sudo apt-get install multiget
```

I get the error:

```
E: Unable to locate package multiget
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MultiGet GUI download manager is not available in the default repositories of any currently supported version of Ubuntu. The last supported version was 14.04. uGet is an alternative GUI download manager to the MultiGet application.

uGet is a lightweight and very powerful download manager application. You can install uGet in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu with this command:

```
sudo apt install uget
```

There is an option in the uGet settings to always show a uGet system tray icon in the notification area of the panel to the left of the clock and volume icons.

#### Features

- Resume downloads  – If your connection is interrupted, you can start right back where you left off with download resuming. (not guaranteed, it's server controlled and cannot be bypassed by a download manager)
- Queue downloads
- Classify downloads in categories
- Batch downloads
- Multi-Protocol – support for downloading files through HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, BitTorrent and Metalink
- Clipboard monitoring
- Import a list of URLs to download via .txt or .html files ✅

uGet also can be launched from the terminal with the command: `uget-gtk`

Comment: Is there a way i can configure proxy settings on uget?

Comment: [uGet: finally my searching ended for a proxy configurable download manager in Linux](https://linuxdreambox.wordpress.com/2012/10/24/uget-finally-my-searching-end-for-proxy-configurable-download-manager-in-linux/) *And it works behind a proxy server. So if you want a download manager for Linux for replacing IDM in Windows, which can use a password-ed proxy, please choose Uget.*